# How would I modify ZXing to optimize for a specific barcode type?

Tags: zxing

ZXing currently performs poorly in my tests of Code 39 and Code 128, which are the only 1D barcode types we're interested in for our apps.

What strategy could we take for optimizing the ZXing code for these types?

What parts of the ZXing source code should we focus on if we wanted to, e.g., start by telling it to stop trying to look for and interpret the other 1D barcode formats (I'm assuming this would help it's success rate in identifying 39/129)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest thing you can do is to not scan for every other format. Just scan with `Code39Reader` and `Code128Reader`, and not `MultiFormatReader` (or, use it, but send hints to restrict the formats that are considered). In an Android app, this will mean that it can examine more frames for just your formats.

If you have a very fast mobile device -- or are working on a desktop computer -- enable `TRY_HARDER` mode.

If you want to hack the code -- the biggest thing to focus on for detection of 1D barcodes is the `Binarizer`. If you have a few months and background in image processing you can probably write something better.

The latter is part of the for-pay release of the Barcode Scanner app, called [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android). If you are willing to part with $3 you can see how much difference better image processing may make to your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look into this. When you say 'just scan for ...' where in the code would we control that part? As for paying $3... we would be willing to pay a few thousand dollars if we could get a vin code scanning version of ZXing (i.e. cross-platform capable) that worked on par with the scanner in autoniq's app. We have not found a barcode scanner app or sdk that can even carry autoniq's water when it comes to VIN codes. ;-(

Comment: BTW I will be purchasing Barcode Scanner+ today, if for no other reason than because I appreciate your work already!

Comment: @Sean Owen: If we are attempting to scan via intent (As I've seen in numerous other threads on this topic, is there a way to specify the type of reader?